# Logging with XSLT

Tags: xslt, logging

How and where could I **output log messages for debug and performance purposes** during an XSLT transformation?

I guess the simplest method is using expressions like this:

```
<xsl:text>message text</xsl:text>
```

here and there in the code, using `xsl:value-of` if needed.

But this method prints the messages in a lot of places in the output file (HTML page in my case), that is where it is called, and not always in the same place (like a log file).

Is this the only way or **is there a better solution?** Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is exactly what `<xsl:message>` is designed for. However, the output location is entirely dependent on the processor. I only have a Mac handy but, sadly, both Firefox and Safari suppress the `<xsl:message>` output. I expect MSIE will do the same.

Given that, I think your best bet is to use `<xsl:comment>` to generate your logs. Something like the below should do the trick:

```
<xsl:template match='my-element'>
   <xsl:comment>Entering my-element template</xsl:comment>
   <p class='my-element'><xsl:apply-templates/></p>
   <xsl:comment>Leaving my-element template</xsl:comment>
</xsl:template>
```

That would give you something like this in the output:

```
<!-- Entering my-element template -->
<p class='my-element'>...</p>
<!-- Leaving my-element template -->
```

Clearly, you can put whatever logging you want into that that output. I would consider creating something like the following and using it to run your logging. This references a global param called 'enable-logging' to determine if logging should occur or not.

```
<xsl:template name='create-log'>
   <xsl:param name='message'/>
   <xsl:if test="$enable-logging = 'yes'">
       <xsl:comment><xsl:value-of select='$message'/></xsl:comment/>
   </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Use this in your stylesheet as:

```
<xsl:template match='my-element'>
   <xsl:call-template name='create-log'>
     <xsl:with-param name='message'/>Entering my-element template</xsl:with-param>
   </xsl:call-template>
   <p class='my-element'><xsl:apply-templates/></p>
   <xsl:call-template name='create-log'>
     <xsl:with-param name='message'/>Leaving my-element template</xsl:with-param>
   </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>
```

One benefit of doing it this way is you can change that `<xsl:comment>` to `<xsl:message>` when in a more complete environment. It is more verbose but more general.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest using `xsl:message` if you are in a development environment such as oXygen or Stylus Studio, and using `xsl:comment` if you are running in the browser. You shouldn't really be debugging your XSLT code in the browser - the browsers I know about are lousy as XSLT debugging tools.

Answer (score 1):

By looking for a solution to this problem, I ended up implementing a logging mechanism in XSLT in similar fashion to log4j, using mostly xsl:message and pure XSLT 2.x. I took some of the answers in this page as inputs. The library is available here: https://github.com/ukuko/log4xslt

Answer (score 0):

Modifying your XSLT itself for the purposes of logging is inevitably going to impact on performance, you're probably better off using an external tool. There are a few available depending on what you're working with:

- [Stylus Studio](http://www.stylusstudio.com/xslt_profiler.html)
- [Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456801.aspx)
- [Altova XMLSpy](http://www.altova.com/xmlspy/xslt-profiler.html)

Comment: thanks! I'm working with XSLT 1.0, HTML output and IE XSLT processor.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use <xsl:message> I think, although where the logging goes is implementation-dependent.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Xalan you can download the "Some Xalan Extensions" jar (net.adamjenkins.sxe on maven).

It works with slf4j and allows for

```
<log:debug message="some message ${somexpath}"/>
```

or

```
<log:info select="./blahblahblah"/>
```

etc for each log level.

Answer (score -1):

A simple hack would be to create a variable with `xsl:variable` and to either just `concat()` new values to it or to set up a `xsl:template` which does the same thing. Then you just need to output this variable at the end of the execution and you can explicitly choose where to show the log.

Comment: Unfortunately, variables are immutable; you can't concatenate values onto the end of one after you've created it.

Comment: Thanks, it's a good point! As variables can't be modified, I guess I need a set of variables which I'll concatenate at the end of the transformation.