# XSLT detect a missing tag

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm having to do an awkward thing of imitating XSD behaviour with XSLT.

In this particular case I'd like to detect a missing element inside a parent element. So far I've come up with the following:

```
  <xsl:template match="grandparenttagname/parenttagname">    
    <!--missing data guard for this template-->
    <xsl:if test="not(tag1name and tag2name and tag3name)">
      A necessary tag is missing!
    </xsl:if>
    ...
```

I was wondering whether it was possible to format the condition in such a way that, inside the conditional xsl tag, I'm able to print the condition that failed (i.e. the first of the tag was missing)?

Thanks for any hints.

Comment: You could log, refer to this excellent post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4849327/logging-with-xslt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no magic here, just use three conditions:

```
<xsl:if test="not(tag1name)">
  tag1name is missing!
</xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="not(tag2name)">
  tag2name is missing!
</xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="not(tag3name)">
  tag3name is missing!
</xsl:if>
```

Comment: Yes that does eactly what I want (prints which condition failed to the result document). I only wish it did not require having a separate tag for each condition. I figured that might be the only way.

Comment: It's because this kind of code gets unwieldy that schema languages were invented.